# Polymorphic function to convert between two types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Is it possible to code in either Haskell98 or with extensions the following function `f`?

```
f :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> c -> d
where (c,d) :: (a,b) || (c,d) :: (b,a)
```

I am attempting to create some generic function to convert between any two types `a` and `b` but am having difficulty with both being somewhat arbitrary. They are immediately set however by the first argument `a ->b`, so I'm hoping this is possible. Any guidance is appreciated...

Thanks!

[EDIT]

The way I see it, my question question boils down to whether haskell's type system supports the `or` keyword... as the intuitive signature of my function is: `f :: (a->b) -> (b->a) -> a -> b or (a->b) -> (b->a) -> b -> a`...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you'd expect to use such a function?

Comment: To achieve cleaner code. Most functions that convert between types `a ->b` are either completely rigid or are polymorphic on only one type. I can implement the latter with type classes but I am not sure how to do it this time. I guess I could use Multiple parameter type classes and declare `Instance a b`, maybe...

Comment: I'd expect to use such a function pretty much all the time. Semantically speaking consolidating `a2b` and `b2a` into `convertAB` just makes sense to me.

Comment: why is that? In any given case it seems you'd know which direction you're applying the conversion int and could just use `a2b` or `b2a` as appropriate: the only time you'd use `convertAB` is when you weren't sure which direction you were doing the conversion in, which seems like a bad idea.

Comment: This is very related to the use of Isos in the lens package. I'd suggest taking a look there, but be warned it can be a very complex library to learn.

Comment: I don't think that it would make code cleaner. On one hand, you get rid of one name; on the other, you need more context to guess what the function is doing when reading code using it. The losses are greater than the gains IMO.

Comment: It can't be done with that type signature.  If you want to use "or", use the either type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that it is possible to do what you want directly, but you can use some workarounds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Converter a b c where
    ($$) :: a -> b -> c

data Conv a b = Conv a b

instance Converter (Conv (a -> b) (b -> a)) a b where
    ($$) (Conv f _) = f

instance Converter (Conv (a -> b) (b -> a)) b a where
    ($$) (Conv _ g) = g

intToString :: Int -> String
intToString = show

stringToInt :: String -> Int
stringToInt = read

printString :: String -> IO ()
printString = print

printInt :: Int -> IO ()
printInt = print

main = do
    let convert = Conv intToString stringToInt
    printString $ convert $$ (12345 :: Int)
    printInt $ convert $$ "12345"
```

I believe this is sufficiently close to what you want. The only difference is a mandatory `$$` operator, but it is inevitable.

**Update:** you can even drop special `Conv` structure and use plain tuples:

```
instance Converter (a -> b, b -> a) a b where
    ($$) (f, _) = f

instance Converter (a -> b, b -> a) b a where
    ($$) (_, g) = g

-- ...
printString $ (intToString, stringToInt) $$ (12345 :: Int)
printInt $ (intToString, stringToInt) $$ "12345"
```

I think this is even closer to your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

As alecb explains, it can't be done in the way your signature suggests, at least through ordinary means (it would require checking the types at runtime). An alternative you might like are [Iso](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) and [Prism](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) from `lens`. `Iso` fits the bill if your conversion functions are total and bijective; if one of the functions is partial you can use a `Prism` instead. Here is a throwaway example:

```
import Control.Lens
import Text.ReadMaybe

stringInt :: Prism' String Int
stringInt = prism' show readMaybe
```

```
GHCi> "3" ^? stringInt
Just 3
it :: Maybe Int
GHCi> 3 ^. re stringInt
"3"
it :: String
```

Comment: This isn't a proper isomorphism. What's the `Int` representation of `"Hello!"`? The correspondence in one direction is only partial, making this a `Prism` rather than an `Iso`.

Comment: @Carl Indeed, it was misleading to leave it that way. I changed the example to use a `Prism` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say we've got these two conversion functions:

```
i2s :: Int -> String
s2i :: String -> Int
```

What would be the type of `g = f i2s s2i`? We'd like `g 1` to be a legal expression, and also `g "one"`. So `g` accepts `Int` and `String`. That leaves us with three options:

1. `g` is a fully polymorphic function - that is, it's first argument is of type `a`. So `g True` and `g [1,2,3]` are also legal. A function so generic has nothing to do with conversion, and you can prove that this sort of functions can't do anything interesting (for example, a function of type `a -> Int` must be constant)
2. `g` expects an argument of a certain typeclass - for example, `show` is a function that accepts only a restricted groups of types (including `Int` and `String`). But now your function is not fully polymorphic - it'll work only for this restricted type group.
3. We can define a new data type for this task:

   ```
   data IntOrString = I Int | S String

   -- the type signature is slightly different
   f :: (Int -> String) -> (String -> Int) -> IntOrString -> IntOrString
   f i2s s2i (I n) = S $ i2s n
   f i2s s2i (S s) = I $ s2i S
   ```

   While this function may be useful in some cases, it's not generic anymore (the only pair it supports is `Int` and `String`).

So the answer is - you can define a function with this type signature, but it will work only for a specific type or typeclass.

EDIT: No, there's no support for a function of type `a -> b where a is Int or String`.  This requires either a dynamic language or a static language that supports subtyping.

Comment: This is pretty much what I want but it has two issues: 1. creating hybrid `data` types 2. The output (`IntOrString`) doesn't seem to automatically cast down to the original types: (`Int` or `String`). Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure how you'd expect to use such a function, but my intuition is no. Suppose we had:

```
intToString :: Int -> String
intToString = show

stringToInt :: String -> Int
stringToInt = read

foo = f intToString stringToInt
```

What is `foo`'s type? You'd have to be able to apply `foo` to both an `Int` and a `String`, and this is generally not possible in haskell: you could apply `foo` to one or the other but not both.

**edit**: This doesn't feel like the whole story -- `foo` could certainly be of type `foo :: c -> d`, but this would allow it to be applied to *any* type, not just `Int` or `String`. Perhaps it would be possible to throw an error when applied to the wrong type. Even if something like that is possible though, it doesn't sound like a good idea.